# numpy: 1d histogram based on 2d-pixel euclidean distance from center

Tags: numpy, histogram, multidimensional-array

I am using python, with scipy, numpy, etc.

I want to compute the histogram of intensity values of a grayscale image, based on the distance of the pixels to the center of mass of the image. The following solution works, but is very slow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import math

# img is a 2-dimensionsl numpy array
img = np.random.rand(300, 300)
# center of mass of the pixels is easy to get
centerOfMass = np.array(list(ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(img)))

# declare histogram buckets
histogram = np.zeros(100)

# declare histogram range, which is half the diagonal length of the image, enough in this case.
maxDist = len(img)/math.sqrt(2.0)

# size of the bucket might be less than the width of a pixel, which is fine.
bucketSize = maxDist/len(histogram)

# fill the histogram buckets
for i in range(len(img)):
    for j in range(len(img[i])):
        dist = np.linalg.norm(centerOfMass - np.array([i,j]))
        if(dist/bucketSize < len(histogram)):
            histogram[int(dist/bucketSize)] += img[i, j]

# plot the img array
plt.subplot(121)
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
imgplot.set_cmap('hot')
plt.colorbar()
plt.draw()

# plot the histogram
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(histogram)
plt.draw()

plt.show()
```

As I said before, this works, but is very slow because you are not supposed to double-loop arrays in this manner in numpy. Is there a more efficient way of doing the same thing? I assume I need to apply some function on all the array elements, but I need the index coordinates as well. How can I do that? Currently it takes several seconds for a 1kx1k image, which is ridiculously slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All numpy binning functions (`bincount`, [`histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), `histogram2d`... have a `weights` keyword argument you can use to do really weird things, such as yours. This is how I would do it:

```
rows, cols = 300, 300
img = np.random.rand(rows, cols)

# calculate center of mass position
row_com = np.sum(np.arange(rows)[:, None] * img) / np.sum(img)
col_com = np.sum(np.arange(cols) * img) / np.sum(img)

# create array of distances to center of mass
dist = np.sqrt(((np.arange(rows) - row_com)**2)[:, None] +
               (np.arange(cols) - col_com)**2)

# build histogram, with intensities as weights
bins = 100
hist, edges = np.histogram(dist, bins=bins, weights=img)

# to reproduce your exact results, you must specify the bin edges
bins = np.linspace(0, len(img)/math.sqrt(2.0), 101)
hist2, edges2 = np.histogram(dist, bins=bins, weights=img)
```

Haven't timed both approaches, but judging from the delay when running both from the terminal, this is noticeably faster.

Comment: Much better answer then mine. Interesting, but unsurprising in retrospect, that np.histogram can take multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Ophion It takes whatever you throw at it, but it always flattens before processing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was playing around with an array of distances as it seemed to be the way to go, but I couldnt make it work.